# Will deleting a lot of your own answers get you answer banned?

Tags: discussion, post-ban, rules

I know that deleting a lot of your own questions will get you banned, but will deleting a lot of your own answers cause a ban? If so what type of ban would it be?

Comment: I don't really see why you would delete a ton of answers for no particular reason.

Comment: Sometimes I think know something only to find out I really don't.

Comment: [Yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105116/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-answers-from-this-account/105119#105119).

Comment: You [can't delete more than 5 answers a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123003/what-happened-to-the-limit-on-deleting-old-answers) I think and if you hit that limit a "possible vanadalism" flags gets raised by "community" automatically.

Comment: I tried searching for duplicates but did not find any. If there is a duplicate I did not notice, I am really sorry. What would be the appropriate action for me to do.

Comment: The duplicate I linked to is not really a duplicate of your question, but it is a FAQ that answers it, and that links to the same source I linked to above as well. So *I feel* it's a duplicate, but others might disagree, of course. If you're expecting a different answer, then wait to see what happens. If the links answered it for you, you could delete this question, or just wait for it to be closed too. Above all: no worries!

Comment: See also: [How does Stack Overflow attempt to prevent low-quality questions and answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/how-does-stack-overflow-attempt-to-prevent-low-quality-questions-and-answers/84669#84669)

Comment: Quick rule of thumb on question/answer bans: picture your contributions to the site, deleted and other, and if that picture looks like the work of someone doing good work you shouldn't be banned for anything. If it looks like the work of a cat dancing on a Markov text generator fed on a strict diet of YouTube comments...

Comment: You donor need the cat. A language model and you-tube comments will do it.

Comment: I also want an answer to this question, but not of the so-called duplicates give me a certain feeling of whether or not I can feel safe deleting my old un-upvoted and un-useful answers.  If there's someone who's able to nominate this question for re-opening.  please do so

Comment: @Shog9 Well, now I know what my next side project is going to be.

Answer (score 4):

> I know that deleting a lot of your own questions will get you banned, but will deleting a lot of your own answers cause a ban?

Probably not. It really depends on what you're trying to do.

There's an automatic ban (similar to the one for questions) that'll kick in if you're fairly new to the site and most of your stuff gets deleted (by you or anyone else). This is *really* helpful for stopping spammers and the like, but if you start contributing *anything* of value it's pretty unlikely you'll ever hit it.

Beyond that, there's some [rate-limiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98746/please-allow-us-to-delete-our-old-subpar-unvoted-answers) built in, and if you hit it the moderators will find out - if it turns out you're rage-quitting (or otherwise deleting *good* stuff), you'll probably get [a short time out](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) and a polite request to stop.

If you're just deleting a few crappy answers here and there while posting more *good* ones, you should be fine. If you plagiarize the work of [Bill's dancing cats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139863/will-deleting-a-lot-of-your-own-answers-get-you-answer-banned#comment473153_139863), you're in trouble.