# Split reputation: one for questions and one for answers

Tags: feature-request, reputation, questions, answers

This request was triggered by the very recent blog post [We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/?cb=1), which announced that now, also retroactively, the askers are given as many reputation points (10) as the answerers for each upvote. This does reward the askers, but also takes away from the answerers by diminishing their **relative** standing. As an arguably extreme example, suppose that Alice has earned a reputation of 1000 points entirely by answering, and Bob has earned a reputation of 600 points entirely by asking; then now Alice will still have 1000 points, while Bob will move ahead of her, now with 1200 points.

Apparently for reasons like that, the mentioned blog post has generated some angry comments (as well as approving ones).

In a comment at [We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/?cb=1), Frank Conijn suggested to

> "split the reputation into one for questions and one for answers. Yes indeed, a two-figure reputation."

This seems to be quite a reasonable suggestion, with no apparent downsides. At least two upsides: it will

1. be more informative;
2. make the dispute between relative merits of asking and answering completely unnecessary.

A [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26514/additional-info-on-user-profile-page-reputation-split) was asked 10 years ago, which now seems to have acquired new relevance. Most of the objections there were about, again, relative merits of asking and answering, which do not seem relevant.

The only objection there of another kind was this:

> "You can't really do it because you can earn a whole bunch of upvotes after you hit the daily rep cap. So any split like this could be really misleading."

I honestly do not understand at all what this problem with the cap is. Whatever it may be, can't it be solved by using caps separately for questions and answers rep points? Or by abolishing the cap altogether?

---

**Added in response to comments and the answer by Glorfindel:**

(i) About privileges, we can just use the total, as is done now.

(ii) I cannot imagine that having two numbers, instead of one, can be considered a "mental load". That would be more informative, though. The suggestion by Liam Morris - Reinstate Monica, to have the two numbers only in the profile information, also seems good.

(iii) Edits to questions, as well as to tag wikis/excerpts (which concern tagging questions), would add to the Q rep. Edits to answers would add to the A rep.

(iv) For bounty, it may be left to the users, where to take their points from.

---

**Remark:** My question is **not a duplicate** of [that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27373/separate-reputation-for-questions-and-answers), despite the title there. Indeed, that question is actually about a very different matter: namely, whether bugs, feature requests, and discussion eventually get reviewed by a moderator.

Comment: This would end up confusing many people.  Gives me a headache just thinking about it.

Comment: @Snow : I cannot imagine how two figures, instead of one, can be confusing.

Comment: How would privileges work then? Are those split per Q and A as well?

Comment: @rene : I think it would be OK to use the total, Q+A, for privileges.

Comment: A better idea would be, rather than splitting the reputation, would be would be a way to view how much reputation a user has gained from both questions and answers. In other words, the number in the top right shows rep from both Q+A, but if you look at the profile, you can see the break down.

Comment: I suggest we just show the total in that case, to prevent confusion

Comment: @rene : I cannot imagine how two figures, instead of one, can be confusing. They are certainly more informative, though.

Comment: lets not assume why people like or dislike the change. just share your own reasoning or reasoning that has actually been stated.

Comment: Do we really need a solution already for something we haven't even conclusively found to be a problem? Let's just see what happens, and if it turns out to be a problem we'll deal with it.

Comment: Have you happened to notice that SE users are, on the whole, pretty averse to change?

Comment: @Snow : "Have you happened to notice that SE users are, on the whole, pretty averse to change?" Yes ,I have noticed that. I don't understand why, though. Have I not addressed all the objections?

Comment: I have added a remark at the end of the answer explaining why my question is not a duplicate of the one at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27373/separate-reputation-for-questions-and-answers .

Answer (score 13):

> This seems to be quite a reasonable suggestion, with no apparent downsides.

Yes, there are many downsides, or at least things that need to be addressed upfront:

- How do you determine privileges? E.g. voting to close questions is an important privilege; if you're writing good answers, you probably know which questions are not answerable and need to be closed, but if you're writing good questions you probably know which ones are bad too. The most obvious option is having *both* reputations count towards the privilege, but then you lose the only real benefit: not having a discussion about the relative merit of questions and answers. An upvote to a question brings you just as close to the privilege as an upvote to an answer does, so they have equal relative merit.
- Two numbers are harder to read than one number; it increases the mental load of parsing the user card.
- What about reputation gained from suggested edits? Especially suggested edits to tag wikis/excerpts? If I suggest an edit which improves the grammar of the post, it doesn't tell anything about my ability to post good questions or answers.
- If you're posting a bounty, are you doing that from your question reputation or answer reputation? Both would make sense, but again it would mean questions and answers have equal merit.

Comment: Not to mention established users getting somewhat annoyed that their large rep count is being reduced to two, smaller, numbers.

Comment: "This seems to be quite a reasonable suggestion, with no apparent downsides" - You'll instantly half/reduce every single person's 'score', there's a overhead of now handling the two numbers in every place they appear. Design changes. There's oh so many downsides which you've not considered.

Comment: "but if you're writing good questions you probably know which ones are bad too"  I am quite sure that author(s) of "How to format string in Java" (and variations) are fully suited to judge and leave open all similar two line questions.

Comment: I am fully aware that simple questions for things that can be found in documentation are often answered by detailed and useful answers and that such Q/A pairs significantly add value to the sites. Reputation is already rather random... adding more value to all questions (great questions are quite rare) is not going to make things any better.

Comment: In general I agree with your answer, splitting reputation is not real solution.

Answer (score 4):

#### One total reputation is a better

Reputation is gained and lost in more ways than just questions and answers. If i posted a 500 rep bounty, where would the reputation be subtracted from? Would it just split half and half between the reputation I gained from both questions and answers? And having users choose which one they want to take from adds an extra unnecessary step into the process.

What about the 100 reputation established users gain from joining other stacks? That is neither reputation from a question nor an answer, its not even related to either of them.

Even the reputation you lose from downvoting, would that 1 point be taken from your question rep or your answer rep? You can’t very well take 0.5 rep from both.

Further, users who have a large amount of reputation now have that number split in half. Whilst the total amount is the same, visually it’d seem smaller and thusly less significant.

---

#### How I would do it

Rather than splitting the reputation you see in the top right corner in half, i’d suggest showing a break down of how you gained that reputation in your user profile. The easiest way to do that would be to have a “Questions” and “Answers” tab in the Reputation section of your user profile.

Here is an example of how that could look, (please excuse the poor photoshopping):[image]

The reputation number in the image, in this case 5017, would change if you clicked on the “Questions” or “Answers” tab, to reflect how much reputation a user has gained from both asking and answering questions.

One thing to note though is that this may not be reflective of the user’s *current* reputation. For example, a user may have 500 rep, but if you were to click on the Questions tab in Reputation, it says they have gained 1000 reputation from questions. Why might this be? Well the user may have posted a bounty for 500 rep, which you would be able to see by looking at their Reputation history.

However, I feel this still achieves what you want - a way to see how much reputation a user has gained from both their questions and answers

---

> "You can't really do it because you can earn a whole bunch of upvotes after you hit the daily rep cap. So any split like this could be really misleading."
>
> I honestly do not understand at all what this problem with the cap is. Whatever it may be, can't it be solved by using caps separately for questions and answers rep points? Or by abolishing the cap altogether?

In regards to the reputation cap, as much as i dislike how low it is, it exists for a reason. It provides a literal hard-cap to how much reputation a single user can gain in a single day. This firstly prevents bots, or people with too much time on their hands, creating accounts just to boost the reputation of one account. It would grant said account with various privileges they haven’t earned, and potentially allowing said account to create a nuisance across an SE site. However, because the cap exists, it gives moderators more time to identify these users who are cheating the system and nip the problem in the bud before it grows.

Secondly, it encourages people not to flood sites with a ton of questions all at once. If you have a lot of questions, its better to spread them out with a few days between, that way you aren’t losing potential reputation because its gone over the daily cap. This allows other people a chance to ask their own questions without being lost in the flood of questions from a single user.

Third the cap prevents established users from growing exponentially. Consider this: If a user posts 1 question or answer, the most reputation they can gain from 100 other users via upvotes is 1000. If a user has 1000 questions or answers however, 100 users can give them up to 100,000 reputation, which might happen within a few weeks, rather than the years it takes with the 250 daily cap. And this is only with 100 other users upvoting, may sites have tens of thousands of users on them, it would not take you long to gain 100k rep without the daily limit.

So in short, abolishing the daily limit is out of the question, and increasing it reduces the amount of time it takes for a user to gain privileges, ones which they may not yet be ready for.

Comment: I think your objections would be addressed if the following two numbers were displayed: T and Q (or T and A), where T:=Q+A+(the rest)=(the current total rep).