# Displaying the questions or answers reputation, in addition to the total reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, questions, answers

This request was triggered by the very recent blog post [We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/?cb=1), which announced that now, also retroactively, the askers are given as many reputation points (10) as the answerers for each upvote. This does reward the askers, but also takes away from the answerers by diminishing their **relative** standing. As an arguably extreme example -- just to make the point clearer, suppose that Alice has earned a reputation of 1000 points entirely by answering, and Bob has earned a reputation of 600 points entirely by asking; then now Alice will still have 1000 points, while Bob will move ahead of her, now with 1200 points.

The mentioned blog post has generated some angry comments (as well as approving ones). Anyhow, I believe what has been said in the above paragraph is a serious concern.

In a comment at [We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/?cb=1), Frank Conijn suggested to

> "split the reputation into one for questions and one for answers. Yes indeed, a two-figure reputation."

This seems to be a reasonable suggestion. At least three upsides: it will

1. be more informative;
2. make the dispute between relative merits of asking and answering completely unnecessary.
3. alleviate the diminishing of answerers' relative standing.

I posted that suggestion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338281/split-reputation-one-for-questions-and-one-for-answers), which met an overall negative response, even though I believe I addressed all the objections there. That request was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27373/separate-reputation-for-questions-and-answers), even though the latter seems to be mainly about whether bugs, feature requests, and discussion eventually get reviewed by a moderator.

Anyhow, all the objections against the two-figure reputation, except possibly one of those objections, can be addressed by the following **modification** of the above two-figure-reputation suggestion:

> to have the following two numbers displayed: T and Q (or T and A), where T:=Q+A+(the rest)=(the current total rep), Q is the rep earned on questions, and A is the rep earned on answers.

The mentioned possible exception is that we would have two different numbers instead of one. However, as stated above, that would be more informative, would make the dispute between relative merits of asking and answering completely unnecessary, and would alleviate the diminishing of answerers' relative standing. This trade-off seems beneficial.

**Added:** This question is **not a duplicate** of the question at [Split reputation: one for questions and one for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338281/split-reputation-one-for-questions-and-one-for-answers) . Indeed, there the proposal was for Q&A, whereas here it is for T&Q or T&A -- see the latter "block quote" above.

Comment: @losif: You're missing the point.  SE wants question askers to have the same standing as answerers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : I understand that. However, this proposal would "make the dispute between relative merits of asking and answering completely unnecessary".

Comment: I have added a remark further explaining why this post is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Let's walk through your reasons...

> 1. be more informative

We already have a way to tell whether a user tends to prefer answers or questions (should you want that information):

[image: question/answer count]

> 2. make the dispute between relative merits of asking and answering completely unnecessary.

There is no dispute. The merits of asking and answering have been judged as equal and will be rewarded equally. The SE staff have spoken.

> 3. alleviate the diminishing of answerers' relative standing.

This is where I really don't understand you. You're saying that by increasing the value of questions, you diminish answers' values? Just because more people have the same rep as you now so you're don't feel as special?

Permissions haven't changed. If you got 10k rep from answers, you'll still have enough rep to view deleted posts along with your other moderator privileges. I don't see how answer-only users have their rep "diminished."

---

Lastly, this would probably be a lot of dev work to calculate (with rep caps and a whole other bunch of edge cases. Not to mention it'd require another whole network-wide rep recalc) and design work to make look good. We have a million and one things we as a community need the corporation to focus on right now. I disagree that this should be one of them.